# how to classify input image using clustering algorithm such as k-mean?

Tags: classification, clustering, svm, k-means, k-medoids

I want to classify ***cifar10*** images using a *clustering algorithm* (**k-mean**). Each image in the ***cifar10*** dataset has a label, so, the results must be a set of labels which are corresponding to the test images.

The input of the proposed code (***k-mean***) is a text file contains a numbers (I do not now what these numbers). The dataset that I used are available here [CoverType](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/covertype). The output that I have is like this::

> 3204.0,184.0,14.0,277.0,41.0,2803.0,223.0,249.0,156.0,966.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0
>   2916.0,231.0,9.0,240.0,30.0,1874.0,206.0,249.0,180.0,1729.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,5.0
>   2782.0,144.0,16.0,210.0,18.0,953.0,241.0,235.0,119.0,735.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3.0
>   3112.0,17.0,9.0,247.0,33.0,5032.0,213.0,221.0,145.0,1104.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0
>   3081.0,86.0,7.0,297.0,44.0,1503.0,230.0,229.0,132.0,2758.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
>   3031.0,44.0,22.0,283.0,19.0,4904.0,219.0,186.0,91.0,3078.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
>   2888.0,150.0,13.0,242.0,56.0,845.0,236.0,239.0,130.0,1611.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0
>   2884.0,37.0,12.0,283.0,29.0,3127.0,219.0,212.0,126.0,2336.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0
>   3001.0,115.0,9.0,418.0,36.0,5227.0,236.0,232.0,127.0,5615.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0
>   3035.0,80.0,5.0,60.0,-4.0,3216.0,227.0,230.0,137.0,5356.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0

I have many questions about this issue::

1- In my case what the inputs should be?

3- I know that the output must be a set of clustering (K) and in this case K=10. The output has 10 lines(statement). Does each line represent a cluster? and what each line mean?

2- How can I use this output of the k-mean to classify an input test image and return its label?

Answer (score 0):

I quite don't understand what you are trying to do, but **K-means** is an unsupervised learning method, hence it doesn't need/use labels.

K-means rather calculates the distances based on the pixel values and so groups the images in clusters.

You could take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@Killavus/naive-approaches-to-solving-cifar10-dataset-image-classification-problem-overview-and-results-636048ff1cc1) medium article.

Comment: I update my question, I wrote something wrong and I correct it. I know that the k-means are unsupervised learning method. but I want to use it with supervised data.

Comment: Why aren't you just downloading the CIFAR-10 data from here: https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html. Normally, the data should consist of 3D numpy arrays that represent RGB images. So the values should range from 0 to 255. You can than use those values for the K-Means algorithm

Comment: because I write the cifar10 as an example. But actually I would work in my own data-set.

Comment: Did you mean the input into the k-means is the images pixels values without any extract features??

Comment: If you would use k-means without any previous feature extraction such as HOG or similar, your input for the algorithm would be indeed only the 3D array of values from 0 to 255. But k-means can be used with any data consisting of numerical values. Of course, it is not guaranteed to give a good clustering. You wrote that you don't know what the values in your dataset represent. This information should be found on the website you downloaded the data from. You could also just perform k-means without the knowledge of your data, which is highly don't recommend.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that k-means will help you anything:

1. It is unsupervised. It will not output a label learned from the data.
2. It probably does not produce satisfactory results on the cigar data set.

Rather I believe you have not understood the problem, and what the k-means algorithm does. Because these two things don't combine.